# Artifactory and Docker for Windows - Pushes Slow Then Fail Most of Time

Tags: windows, docker, artifactory

Over the past 6 months, we've used Docker for Windows to build both Linux and Windows container images.

We just started building the images far more often, and we now find that the `docker push` commands are failing very often. Many of the small layers upload successfully, although they go very slow, and have to be retried several times.  Eventually though, the bigger layers retry over and over and never succeed.  I've let them go for over an hour on a 2 GB image and it still never finished so I cancelled.  This is all local LAN, superfast, no WAN.  As a result, currently, we have to build the Linux images from Dockerfile on every place they are used.

It used to be the case that `pushes` of Windows images failed.  Now it seems that pushes of Linux images are failing to push, and Windows images `push` just fine. I've tried from 4 separate Docker hosts, all fail to upload in the same way.

When I build the exact same Linux images on a Linux host, and push to Artifactory, it works with no problem.

For a long time, i thought it was something with NGinx.  But, since the Linux host upload works fine, I now think it's some difficult to isolate nuance between:

Docker for Windows
NGinx
Artifactory

I found some other posts about the topic in a general sense, most seemed old/resolved/different, or related to basic support of Windows containers.

Feedback welcome, thanks.

Environment:

```
Windows 10 10.0.17134  
Docker CE: Version 18.06.1-ce-win73 (19507) (Stable)  
Artifactory Version 6.3.2
```

reproduce:

```
docker pull centos/python-36-centos7
docker tag centos/python-36-centos7 my_artifactory_server/docker/centos/python-36-centos7
docker push my_artifactory_server/docker/centos/python-36-centos7
```

After 3 minutes, here is my progress:

```
5bef68a04db7: Retrying in 1 second
0ef705c3d148: Pushing [==================================================>]  262.7kB/262.7kB
ef9db94a65b7: Pushing [==================================================>]  262.7kB/262.7kB
832dfe5d9c79: Pushing [====>                                              ]  19.34MB/226.8MB
4a45879b2884: Pushing [====>                                              ]  33.58MB/377MB
20a61b68701f: Pushing [==================================================>]  3.408MB/3.408MB
0bb055614aec: Pushing [==================================================>]  262.7kB/262.7kB
84293cc95fdf: Pushing [==================================================>]  38.27MB/38.27MB
f972d139738d: Pushing [==========>                                        ]  62.24MB/297MB
```

Comment: `retry` in docker push usually means a timeout or error returned by the target repo, did you check in your nginx logs to see what responses are returned during these failed push operations?  did you check the Artifactory log and request log ?

Comment: Artifactory logs show nothing useful, I didn’t have access to nginx but will ask for those logs next chance I get.

Comment: Artifactory's `request.log` can show you if the requests are even reaching it (or 'get stopped' at nginx),  the return code and request path can also help in identifying your issue.

Comment: returning to this now after some time. the requests are definitely reaching, as you can see, most of the layers get part way through downloading and then just stop.

Comment: Was just able to push a docker image from Linux laptop without an issue.  Docker on Windows seems to be part of the root cause.  Both Docker Desktop 2.0.0.3 / Docker EE 18.09.6 on Server 2019 fail to upload to Artifactory 6.9.1.  Fails to push both Windows and Linux containers with same symptoms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was clearly all due to various nuances of LCOW not behaving the same as Linux hosts in various capacities.  Since Docker on Windows is being completely redesigned to work with WSL2 and LCOW itself is going to be deprecated, I'm saying that the solution is to move to WSL2 when it's available and never expect this work. Suggest locking the thread.